# PHP page with JSON doesn't work with ISH app on iPad

Tags: php, json, alpine-linux

I am trying to use a code that works on my Linux server in PC, installing it on my iPad using ISH app, but it doesn't work.

I installed apache with: https://github.com/timdreier/ish-webserver-setup

```
<?php
$jsonPHP = file_get_contents('/var/www/localhost/htdocs/xxx/xxx/datos.json');
//echo file_get_contents('/var/www/localhost/htdocs/xxx/xxx/datos.json');


$jsondec = (0);
$jsondec = json_decode($jsonPHP);
?>
```

If I use "echo" it show the JSON, but when I use json_decode, it doesn't works..

I don't know what can I do.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors? Does $jsonPHP get the value you expected? What other debugging have you done? You haven't given us much to work with

Comment: Yes, here you can ser the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function json_decode() in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/SantanderPHP/index2.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/SantanderPHP/index2.php on line 18

Comment: Most likely one of the [existing solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=Call+to+undefined+function+json_decode) out there already will help you